# Pandas pie chart: bundle categories as "other"?

Tags: pandas, data-visualization, data-science

Given a categorical variable with a few categories making up the great majority of the instances, and several categories making up a very small amount of the instances, plotting a pie chart of it will look like the following:

[image]

How can I combine the bottom N categories as "other" so the chart is easier to read?

[image]

The only way I can think of is to manually see which categories make the chart messy, then eventually choose a threshold when manually creating a new dataframe that bundles categories:

```
SOME_THRESHOLD = 162342

def combine_other(row):
    if row.fuel > SOME_THRESHOLD:
        return row['index']
    return 'Other'
f = df.fuel.value_counts(dropna=False).to_frame().reset_index()
f.loc[:, 'combined_label'] = f.apply(combine_other, axis=1)
f.groupby('combined_label').fuel.sum()\
   .plot.pie(autopct='%.1f')
```

Comment: You could express the threshold in percent and divide value counts by the DataFrame size. At least this way, the threshold value should be independent of the DataFrame you are using.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem `value_count(normalize=True)`.

Comment: Of course this exists! Thanks.